# Passing request parameter with href without they visible in request (Making href Post instead of Get)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, servlets

I have a html table in my JSP where one column is a anchor element.On click of this anchor tag I need to call a Servlet.In this request I append the file name to the as a request parameter along with the servlet call.
like

```
<table>
<tr><td>
<a href="/FileDownLoadServlet.dwnld?fileName=Test1.pdf&key=123456" target="_blank">Test1Container</a>
<td></tr>
<tr><td>
<a href="/FileDownLoadServlet.dwnld?fileName=Test2.pdf&key=789123" target="_blank">Test2Container</a>
<td></tr>
</table>
```

The servlet in writes the file to response so the respective pdf gets opened in new tab.

The issue is the new tab that is opened in its address bar the entire URL is getting showed up.May be because of GET request if href.
I want to avoid this and show the original URL without the name of servlet and its request parameters.May be if possible showing only file name in the address bar after the context name will do.
Please suggest.

Comment: for what purpose you need to hide your entire pdf url?

Comment: We dont want to display the Servlet name with the filename and key parameters in the browser header due to some security constraints.URL can be like https://<domainname>/<contextname>/Test1.pdf and not like https://<domainname>/<contextname>/FileDownLoadServlet.dwnld?fileName=Test1.pdf&key=123456

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/9qacod03/

```
<form id = "pdfViewer" method = "post" action = "/FileDownLoadServlet.dwnld" target="_blank">
  <input type = "hidden" name = "fileName" value = "" />
  <input type = "hidden" name = "key" value = "" />
</form>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a class = "pdfLink" fileName = "Test1.pdf" key = "123456" href = "#">Test1Container</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a class = "pdfLink" fileName = "Test2.pdf" key = "789123" href = "#">Test2Container</a>
    <td>
  </tr>
</table>

$(".pdfLink").click(function () {

  var fileName = $(this).attr("fileName");
  var key = $(this).attr("key");

  $("#pdfViewer").find("[name=fileName]").val(fileName);
  $("#pdfViewer").find("[name=key]").val(key);

  $("#pdfViewer").submit();

});
```

Comment: I think this will solve my problem.Will try this.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Let me know if it works for You.

And don't forget to up-vote my answer.

Comment: It worked for me.One issue is that as we have mentioned the target as _blank, the pdf file get opened in the new tab but the tab name has the Servlet name on it.Is there any way by which i can rename the tab to the pdf file name. when user opens multiple pdf from different rows in the browser he is not able to identify which file is of which name.

Comment: $("#pdfViewer").attr("action", "/FileDownLoadServlet.dwnld?" + fileName);

Comment: Add the above line before: $("#pdfViewer").submit();

Comment: Added what you suggested.This maked URL look like http://<domainname>/<contextname>/FileDownLoadServlet.dwnld?Test1.pdf and same name appears as tab title. Is there any way that the tab title have the pdf file name like this URL has http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_tutorial.pdf

Comment: You will need to use .htaccess